# Help with problematic layout using MigLayout

Tags: java, layout, grid, alignment, miglayout

I've been trying to align some objects in my java project in a certain way but with no success. I am using MigLayout for the layout and this is how I would like it to look:

[image: Desired layout]

1. The sidebar should have a static width (220px) and be docked left.
2. The right column should have a fluid width and expand according to window size.
3. The footer should be docked to the bottom and have a static height, fluid width.

This is the code that I have got now:

```
this.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, wrap 2", "[30%][70%]", "grow"));

this.add(sourceList, "w 30%");
this.add(listView, "w 70%");
this.add(bottomBar.getComponent(), "growx, push, span");
```

I've been trying to understand the usage instructions but they are hard to understand. I was hoping someone here had knowledge about working with MigLayout and could help me.

Comment: You can get this done with GridBagLayout -- not sure if MigLayout is the best option here.

Comment: I know that there are other Layout options, but from what I've heard, MigLayout is the best one since it allows much more placement and dimension freedom.

Comment: @Jonathon do what you're doing. MigLayout and JGoodies FormLayout are the two best out there. Don't go to GridBag which is just painful to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) which helps very much is building these out. It's free, and supports MigLayout too.

Doing what you just described in it gets me:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[220][grow]", "[grow][]"));
add(sidebar, "cell 0 0,grow");
add(main, "cell 1 0,grow");
add(bottom, "cell 0 1 2 1,grow");
```

This keeps the sidebar at a fixed 220 (from the column spec in the constructor) and the bottom at a static height with the preferred size. The width of column 2 and height of column 1 will grow to fill, as will the components in each cell.

Comment: Hello, thanks the comment. I tried the above code and it works good except for one minor detail. I get a spacing to the right of the sidebar and also a spacing on top of the bottom. Is there any way to remove these? Also, I will look into WindowBuilder!

Comment: Make the constructor MigLayout("gap 0px 0px", "[220][grow]", "[grow][]")); and I think that should do it.